# Material JS not working on ng-view but worked on main file

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've been struggling with using **ng-view** and **material js** for my subview of my application.

**material js** cannot work on subview with it work on main page.

```js
var eSepration = angular.module('eSeparation', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial','ngAnimate','ngMessages','ngAria']);
 
eSepration .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/myApproval', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/view/my_approval.html',
        controller: 'app/components/controllers/MyApproval'
      }).
      when('/separationProcess', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/view/separation_process.html',
        controller: 'app/components/controllers/SeparationProcess'
      }).
        when('/fareTheWell', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/view/fare_the_well.html',
        controller: 'app/components/controllers/FareTheWell12'
      }).
        when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/view/test.html',
        controller: 'app/components/controllers/mainController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/myApproval'
      });
  }]);
```

```html
<html >
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.timesinternet.in/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="icon" href="http://www.timesinternet.in/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <title>empower separation</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">  
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="assets/css/empower_separation.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="eSeparation" ng-cloak>
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input ng-model="user.firstName">
          </md-input-container>
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Primary</md-button>
 <header>
  <div class="logo"><a  href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="empower separation" width="200"></a>
   <div type="button" id="pollSlider-button" class="navbar_icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" onclick="moving_Image()"><span class="icon-bar"><img src="assets/img/menu_ico.png" alt=""/></span>  </div>
  </div>
 </header>

<div class="container">
 <div class="sections">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="sideholder">
     <nav class="mynav">
      <ul>
       <li class="current"><a href="#myApproval"> MY APPROVALS
       </a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">INVOLUNTARY <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px; padding:4px;"></span> </a>
        <ul>
         <li> <a href="#">Mission Statement </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Our Staff </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Our Promise </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Ethics &amp; Legal </a></li>
         <li> <a href="#">Future Goals </a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li> <a href="#separationProcess">INITATE </a></li>
       <li> <a href="#fareTheWell">Fare Well </a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Demo </a></li>

      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div ng-view> 

   </div>


  </div>
 </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/company-main30f4.js?v=3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Primary</md-button>


<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div class="my_container">
<div class="heading">Do you feel like moving?
</div>

<div>
<form class="bs-example bs-example-form">

<div class=" form_container">


<div class="field">
<label class="small">Let’s try to work something out
</label>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-2 col-xs-12">
<div class="styled-select slate">
  <select>
    <option>Talk To</option>
    <option>The second option</option>
    <option>The third option</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="field">
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-2 col-xs-12">
<div class="styled-select slate">
  <select>
    <option>Write To</option>
    <option>The second option</option>
    <option>The third option</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="field" >
   
</div>




</div>

</form>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are mixing both bootstrap and material design

Comment: yes, but it work on main page  index.html , in sub view when i call inside ng-view it cannot work.

Comment: hey please any one help me

Comment: Material Js effect are not working on Sub view inside ng-view but it work on index.html main page ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download arrive.js and include before material.js

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/master/minified/arrive.min.js

that works for me.